# Swift: How to handle tightly coupled views?

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, decoupling

I have a `UIViewController` that is part of a `UINavigationController` and I want a custom view in my navigation bar. The code is then something like this:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.customNavigationView = MyNavigationView()
        self.navigationItem.titleView = self.customNavigationView
    }
}
```

`MyViewController` and `MyNavigationView` are tightly coupled in a sense - they form a single piece of UI and only make sense when used together. I wonder what the preferred way to handle such cases is pattern-wise. In particular, what's the preferred way to send messages from `MyNavigationView` to `MyViewController` (such as buttons tapped).

I saw the following options:

- Use a delegate pattern, create a `MyNavigationViewDelegate` protocol and add a `delegate` property to `MyNavigationView`. While the most object-oriented approach, it seems a bit "over-engineered" to me and has a lot of overhead for something that is basically a single unit of UI
- Make `MyNavigationView` an inner class of `MyNavigationController` to indicate their strong relationship. Seems fine, but I like to have a file per class for easy navigation
- Use a `weak var myViewController: MyViewController?` in `MyNavigationView`. I don't think the variable should be an optional, though, because semantically it is not
- Use a `let myViewController: MyViewController` and a custom initializer in `MyNavigationView` that sets it. Seems the best option to me right now, but I'm not sure if it can create a memory leak since its a strong reference cycle
- Thanks to @Mohsen Hossein pour: Sending notifications from `MyNavigationView` to `MyViewController`.

I wonder what other people's thoughts on this are. Is there are clear pattern that should be used here or is it a matter of taste?

Comment: Why would your view know anything about its host? what information do you want to share with the parent ?

Comment: I guess that is exactly my point/question: Usually the view wouldn't, but since the two are so tightly coupled in this case it seems to me like it is better than having the huge overhead of having a delegate etc.. The view would, for example, send messages about UI events (button pressed etc.) back to the controller

Comment: I wouldn't do that, instead I would expose the button itself (make it property of the view).

And in the viewcontroller after initializing the view I would assign the gesture recognizers to be handled by the controller itself. that way the view still doesn't know anything about its host

Comment: I used this approach and it feels the most satisfying so far because there is no reference from the view to its host, just as you said, but it's still fairly low on overhead and flexible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While any answer to this question is ultimately opinionated in the MVP design pattern a view should not contain any business logic, just display logic. which means it should not know anything about its host.

The way I would approach it is to write the connection code and the interaction code in its host instead.

```
class MyNavigationView : UIView
{
   var button : UIButton!

}

class ViewController : UIViewController   
{
      override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       self.customNavigationView = MyNavigationView()
       self.navigationItem.titleView = self.customNavigationView
       // here you can assign gesture recognizers or add event listeners 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a notification if you only need to know if something happened in the other view, it is easier and faster to implement, if you need more explanation on how to use notifications please ask and I can edit my answer and explain some more.

Comment: That is certainly an option I have not mentioned above, and I will edit it in. I would argue that notifications have an extremely low coupling, though, which is quite the opposite of what the views semantically are